# How to increase the quality of the map using gmapping and Hokuyo sensor

Tags: navigation, mapping, hokuyo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I built a map from the scan a Hokuyo lidar sensor using slam_gmapping package. The problem is that the generated map of the area that I scanned is very small with low quality and resolution. I would appreciate If you suggest me by changing of which parameters of Hokuyo and gmapping I could build a high map map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222818/how-to-increase-the-quality-of-the-map-using-gmapping-and-hokuyo-sensor/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have `~delta` parameter in `gmapping` for resolution of the map. You can decrease this value. But of course in exchange for performance. You can check [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping).

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0